# Stop superscript affecting line spacing

Tags: line-spacing, line

I was wondering whether there was a way to stop the superscript and subscript affecting the line spacing, any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ordtext}{Ordinary text to fill several lines. }
\newcommand{\testparagraph}{\noindent
 \ordtext\ordtext\ordtext
 Some math with sub and superscripts:
 $X^{\frac{1}{2}}_ + Y_2 + \frac{1}{2}$.
 \ordtext\ordtext\ordtext
}
\textwidth=2in

\begin{document}

\baselineskip=10pt
\testparagraph
\medskip

\lineskip=0pt
\testparagraph
\medskip

\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen
\testparagraph

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\baselineskip=10pt` is impossibly tight spacing and to have that and inline math with superscripts and fractions is setting impossible constraints. You could hide the height of the superscripts but it will overprint the text above.

Comment: your last example has even linespacing (but the superscript over-prints) isn't  that what you ask for? You could write the superscript as 1/2 rather than  \frac{1}{2}

Comment: You may find it instructive to learn how some math textbooks are designed in order to avoid uneven line skips if there's inline math material. The book [Concrete Mathematics](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/gkp.html) (2nd ed. 1994) by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik is -- *typographically* speaking -- probably best known for its use of the Concrete Roman text font and the Euler math font. But it's also noteworthy for the choice of a 10pt font size along with a 13pt baseline skip. That's the *exact opposite* approach to the 10pt baseline skip used in the your MWE.